# Implementing my own treeset in java

Tags: java, treeset

I'm implementing my own java treeset. I think the underlying data structure is a BST and each node in the tree contains Object type data field. However, I stuck at how to compare two Object type data using natural ordering comparator. Is there a compareTo function that compares two objects and return the value of their natural ordering? I'm also thinking using hashcode as index key for each node and do comparison based on that. But it seems that distinct object might have same hashcode. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: An example of your existing code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

instead of BST consider RBT (Red black tree). look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) for more reference.

Now your MyTreeSet can take two kind of objects.
1. Object of java given wrapper class like String, Integer, Long etc Or
2. Object of your own written custom classes.

If your data structure needs to support case 1 one then order can be done easily based on compareTo method which is implemented by all java given wrapper class. You only need to call compareTo method to know which object is greater, equal or lesser than others based on it's return value 0, negative and positive value.

For case 2, that means your MyTreeSet needs to take object of custom classes also then you should implement Comparable interface to your custom classes and write your comparison algorithm there. For example if you want MyTreeSet should take Employee class object then implement Comparable method in Employee class and write implementation of compareTo method based on how emp1 will be compared to emp2. You may want to sort them based on their employee ids.

Hope it helps you.